# Azure delete backup vault fails with 'associated container'

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I am cleaning out some old items from my azure account and cannot remove an older version Bacup Vault.

I get the following error when I try to delete it:

> Vault cannot be deleted as there are existing resources within the
>   vault. Please ensure there are no backup items, protected servers or
>   backup management servers associated with this vault. Unregister the
>   following containers associated with this vault before proceeding for
>   deletion : **COMPUTER-NAME**. Unregister all containers from the vault and then
>   retry to delete vault

Notice the **COMPUTER-NAME** 
That is the name of my computer, but I can not find the Azure back up agent installed on that computer.  I also cannot find the computer name container in any storage containers in my entire azure account.

Can someone help me figure out how to remove these items

thanks in advance

First screenshot shows the Backup vault and the error message I get when I try to delete.
[image]

the second screenshot shows the BackupItems that remain, but I cannot delete them.
[image]

the red boxes cover my COMPUTER-NAME

Comment: It would be more convenient if you provide related screenshot.

Comment: @JanleyZhang added, thanks

Comment: @JKing If you click `...` what is the result.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT clicking the ... gives only one option "pin to dashboard".  I was expecting the delete option to be there.  I still don't have this solved.

Comment: I think I just ran into this same problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066689/10577234) was my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my previous answer was turned into a comment due to brevity. Here's an update to make it a better answer anyway. Answer from that link quoted below for reference.

> I have not mapped this answer to the corresponding Azure commands, but I was  able to find my way to a solution via the Azure Portal. The steps were as follows:
>
> 1. Selected my Recovery Service resource
> 2. Under the **Manage** section, clicked *Backup Infrastructure*
> 3. Under **Management Servers**, clicked *Protected Servers*
> 4. In the list that followed, clicked on the row where my **Protected Server > Count** was greater than 0, in my case, *Azure Backup Agent* (because the backup agent was installed on my Windows Desktop)
> 5. Clicked on my server name in the **Protected Server** list
> 6. Clicked *Delete* in the card for my protected server
>
> After that completed, I was able to delete the entire vault. These steps may be helpful if you have other Backup Infrastructure resources and possibly even Site Recovery Infrastructure resources associated with a vault.
>
> Update: It seems like there's an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6595) for *Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem* not having any capacity to return MARS backup items which is ultimately what the issue here was.