# Receiving an Error when deleting an Azure Recovery Services Vault

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I have an old Azure Recovery Services vault for an on-premise Windows Desktop that I am trying to remove after decommissioning said desktop. Azure is responding with this error message:

> Vault cannot be deleted as there are existing resources within the vault. Please ensure there are no backup items, protected servers or backup management servers associated with this vault. Unregister the following containers associated with this vault before proceeding for deletion : VAULT-NAME. Unregister all containers from the vault and then retry to delete vault

Where VAULT-NAME is the name of my vault.

I followed the steps referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44405120/10577234) but could not get past this step due to the fact that there is not a corresponding "Windows" or "WindowsServer" option for the WorkloadType parameter.

```
$item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container -WorkloadType AzureSQLDatabase
```

Skipping the item retrieval and disable steps and instead trying to unregister the container and remove the vault with the following commands was of no use on account of still having backups associated with the container.

```
Unregister-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -Container $container
Remove-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Vault $vault
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not mapped this answer to the corresponding Azure commands, but I was able to find my way to a solution via the Azure Portal. The steps were as follows:

1. Selected my Recovery Service resource
2. Under the **Manage** section, clicked *Backup Infrastructure*
3. Under **Management Servers**, clicked *Protected Servers*
4. In the list that followed, clicked on the row where my **Protected Server Count** was greater than 0, in my case, *Azure Backup Agent* (because the backup agent was installed on my Windows Desktop)
5. Clicked on my server name in the **Protected Server** list
6. Clicked *Delete* in the card for my protected server

After that completed, I was able to delete the entire vault. These steps may be helpful if you have other Backup Infrastructure resources and possibly even Site Recovery Infrastructure resources associated with a vault.

Update: It seems like there's an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6595) for *Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem* not having any capacity to return MARS backup items which is ultimately what the issue here was.